# Как залить фигуру и выбрать толщину рамки?

Tags: pascal

Задача:

> Создать треугольник со свойствами:
>    - Контур фигуры = зеленый.
>    - Толщина рамки 3.
>    - Заливка фигуры = желтый.

Вот что я попытался сделать

```
setcolor(2);
line(300,100,500,300);
line(500,300,150,300);
line(150,300,300,100);
```

А вот как сделать заливку контура и широты не помню.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FloodFill](http://delphid.dax.ru/www/doc/doc.php?key=FloodFill) вам в помощь.

*Паскаль - как много в этом звуке... )*

Comment: А можете мене под мою задачу сделать параметры, так как не помню практически не чего. тольшина через setfilestyle. Вы не могли написать?

Comment: Паскаля под рукой нет, к сожалению( Но полагаю что вам нужно вот это:

<a href="http://tpdn.ru/guide/pf/setlinestyle/">SetLineStyle</a>

<a href="http://tpdn.ru/guide/pf/setfillstyle/">SetFillStyle</a>

По сути должно хватить. Там и все константы есть.

Comment: setcolor(2);
line(300,100,500,300);
line(500,300,150,300);
line(150,300,300,100);
SetLineStyle(3,2);
SetFillStyle(1,цвет) ?

Comment: Ну нет же) Алгоритм для себя опишите по-русски, там и понятно станет. Установить цвет и толщину линий (SetLineStyle), Нарисовать линии (line), Установить цвет и тип заливки (SetFillStyle), залить (FloodFill).

Answer (score 0):

SetPenColor - для цвета границы, FloodFill - заливка в контуре, толщину не помню

Answer (score -1):

```
SetPenWidth(толщина);
```

Это толщина пера